# range-slider foundation 5 bug

Tags: jquery, symfony-forms, zurb-foundation-5

```
<div class="small-12 large-3 columns">
    {{ form_label(form_ad.price) }}
    <div class="hidden">
        <div class="range-slider round" data-slider data-options="start: 0; end: 500; step: 0.01; initial: 0; display_selector: #price;">
            <span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0"></span>
        </div>
        <span id="price"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

my `range-slider-handle` when I give the click appears half the position forward

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: What browser are you seeing this happen in? My jsFiddle works as expected - http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/k92p55ps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided using the jQuery-ui

[jQuery-ui range](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)